# If I give route in links in Laravel all of them become active

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have an issue. If i give to my links routes, all of them becomes active

```
<li class="{{ (strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'dashboard') == 0) ? 'active' : '' }}">
<a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
<i class="uil uil-dashboard me-2 d-inline-block"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
```

Can somebody explain me why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` returns `int(0)` when `Route::currentRouteName()` is `'dashboard'` and `bool(false)` otherwise.

You're using the `==` operator which is NOT strict comparison. Try using `===` instead.

```php
false == 0  // true
false === 0 // false
```

Comment: @=I guess you dont get my question. But whatever i did try it, and it didnt work

Comment: I did get your question and that is the logic error I'm seeing there. As long as you use `==` instead of `===`. `strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'dashboard') == 0)` will always be `true`. If you changed that in your view, saved the file and saw no change, try also clearing the view cache. `php artisan view:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `request()->route()->named()` method :

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#inspecting-the-current-route

```
<li class="{{ request()->route()->named('dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
          <i class="uil uil-dashboard me-2 d-inline-block"></i>Dashboard
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: It doesnt matter if i try this way, or the way i did. The problem is if i give `{{ route('dashboard) }}` to href, this given link become active, no matter if im on that page

Comment: if you try to show the current route name {{ request()->->route()->getName() }} what name is it ? If it's also "Dashboard" you might have an issue in your routes file